# RabbitMQ messages are not recieved in order by the listener

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I have a scenario where the order of messages received at the receiving end is some times not in order.

**My scenario:**

**MACHINE A:**

- I am sending a series of messages(around 12 messages) from machine A to machine B over rabbitMQ shovel.
- The messages are are of different sizes. The over all size of 12 messages is close to 8mb.
- Once the 12 messages are sent, i am also sending "complete message" in the end to MACHINE B.

**MACHINE B:**

- This is the recieving machine. This machine has a single listener. It recieves all the messages sent by MACHINE A. Once it recieves "sending complete", its obvious that this is the last message from MACHINE A and MACHINE B starts processing all the messages that were recieved.

  **MACHINE B Configiration**

  ```
      <rabbit:listener-container
          connection-factory="connectionFactory">
          <rabbit:listener ref="onMessageCommand"
              queue-names="CommandQueue" />
      </rabbit:listener-container>
      <bean id="onMessageCommand"
          class="com.mypackage.command.messaging.OnMessageListner">
          <property name="callBackObject" ref="callbackDisEvent" />
          <property name="template" ref="amqpTemplate" />
      </bean>

      <bean id="callbackDisEvent" class="com.mypackage.command.OperationSettingsListener"></bean>
  ```

  **MACHINE A CODE**

  public void sendMessage(String messageToSend,String machineBID) 
  { 
      Message sendMessage = new Message(messageToSend, new MessageProperties());
      RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = 
      messagingApplContext.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
      rabbitTemplate.send(message, machineBID + ".command"); 
  }

**ISSUE:**
Some times i am observing that one "sending complete" is recived by the MACHINE B just before some setting. Ideally "sending complete" should always be the last message recived by the MACHINE B.

May i please know what can be the issue here.

Comment: You need to show code and configuration (producer and consumer).

Comment: i narrowed down the issue to next level.

Comment: **FROM MACHINE A:**
After 5th message(1mb),10th message(0.75mb),12th message(4.7mb) a small sized message are being sent.
I am printing every message sent in the logs.


**FROM MACHINE B:**
I am printing every message recieved in the log. The recieving order was not in sync with sending order.
Here, the small messages which were sent just after big messages as mentioned above are recieved first and then big sized messages arrive.

Comment: May i know is this expected behaviour. Doesnt RabbitMQ provide guaranteed delivery of messages in order?
Is RabbitMQ taking time in processing the big messages before it puts in the queue and meanwhile if a small message comes, its processed fast and gets an entry in the queue even before the big message. 
If this is true, my sent log prints in message A doesnt guarantee that messages are placed in the same order in the queue.

Comment: **NOTE:**
There is single listener in MACHINE B so there is not way that messages are recieved in round robin fashion by the listeners. All must be sequentially 
recieved as per the order of the messages in the queue.

Comment: My question is does RabbitTemplate.send create threads internally to process the  messages and then push into the queue?

Comment: @GaryRussell .. Please find the information above and also please reply for my last question

Comment: Don't put code and configuration in comments; it's too hard to read; delete those comments and edit the question instead. Messages sent on the same channel will be sent in order. If you are using different threads to send messages they can be sent out of order. Also, Spring AMQP caches channels so it's possible for sends to occur on different channels, even on a single thread. Since version 2.0, you can enforce all operations to occur on the same channel, using [Scoped Operations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#scoped-operations).

Comment: Thanks for the response @GaryRussell . As u mentioned, the cached channels may be causing problems to me. Can you please provide some links for sample programs to implement scoped operations in the right manner. or a sample code will also suffice

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using message acknowledgements. More info here https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: i am not using message acknowledgements. I am just sending messages and in the end i am sending "sending complete". Cant i assume that "sending complete" will always be the last message to be recieved?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please provide some links for sample programs to implement scoped operations in the right manner. or a sample code will also suffice

The [link I provided you](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#scoped-operations) has this example:

```
Collection<?> messages = getMessagesToSend();
Boolean result = this.template.invoke(t -> {
    messages.forEach(m -> t.convertAndSend(ROUTE, m));
    t.waitForConfirmsOrDie(10_000);
    return true;
});
```

You just have to make sure all the sends are performed within the scope of an `invoke` call...

```
Boolean result = this.template.invoke(t -> {
    ...
    t.send(...)
    ...
    t.send(...)
    ...
    return true;
}
```

And they will all go on the same channel. The return doesn't have to be boolean, it can be anything you want, even `null`.

```
this.template.invoke(t -> {
    ...
    t.send(...)
    ...
    t.send(...)
    ...
    return null;
}
```